# Excluding certain unique IDs and then grouping the remaining ones

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm building a car booking website. And there is a cars tables that is like this:

Cars

- CarID
- CarModel
- CarMake
- Registration

And also a reservations table like this:

Reservations:

- ReservationID
- CarID
- StartDate
- EndDate

So When a user inputs the dates which they would like to book a car I query my reservations table:

If the dates are already in the reservation table I want to get that car ID, and then exclude that car from the list the user is shown, so they can not book it.

My problem is that I have multiple cars in the Database that are the same mode and make but have a different CarID and Registration.

I also group the cars by model so that a user is only shown one car of a certain type.

```
$carstring = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars {$statement} AND deleted = 'no'" GROUP BY CarModel);

$getcars = $carstring;
while($searchcars = mysql_fetch_array($getcars)) {



   $checkreservations = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE startDate = '".$sqlcoldate."' and carID = '".$searchcars['carID']."'");
   $thiscar_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($checkreservations);
```

So as you can see at the minute I can tell which cars are taken in the reservations table, and I can echo out true or false from the `num_rows`

However I think it is the wrong way around because what I want to do is find out which cars by `CarID` are already taken, and then exclude them from the `$getcars` query loop that displays all the cars to the user, then group by model.

Can anyone tell me a way to do this, or even a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to exclude the cars that are reserved is awith a subquery that gets all cars that ARE reserved and than stating in the main query that those cars are not allowed with the CarID NOT IN construction

```
<?php 

    // select all cars that are not reserved at sqlcoldate
    $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM Cars
    WHERE CarID NOT IN (
        SELECT CarID
        FROM Reservations
        WHERE StartDate > '".$sqlcoldate."' and EndDate < '".$sqlcoldate."'
    )
    GROUP BY CarModel";

    // execute that query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // if there are no results print a message
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No cars found";
        exit; // Exit the function, because there is nothing to do
    }

    // else print all available cars
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Model available car is :" . $row["CarModel"] . " </br>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't actualy test it. But it should work

```
SELECT c.* FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN reservations r
ON c.carID=r.carID AND
selected_date BETWEEN r.startDate AND r.endDate
WHERE r.carID is null
```